# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 breaks things?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, visual-studio-2010

I'm using this little code snippet to catch Java processes with certain parameters:

```
string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = 'javaw.exe'";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
{
    string cmdLine = obj.GetPropertyValue("CommandLine").ToString();
    if (cmdLine.IndexOf("someapplication") != -1)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This code worked like a charm just a couple of days ago when I didn't have SP1 for VS2010. Now it throws a null pointer exception on line 7. I'm trying to compile for .NET Framework 2.0.

Help!? :/

Comment: What makes you believe that Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is the culprit? That seems highly unlikely.

Comment: This started to happen after I upgraded to SP1. But the issue wasn't there, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has less to do with SP1 and more to do with a Java update. Just check for `null`:

```
string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = 'javaw.exe'";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
{
    object cmdLineValue = obj.GetPropertyValue("CommandLine");

    if(cmdLineValue != null) {
        string cmdLine = cmdLineValue.ToString();
        if (cmdLine.IndexOf("someapplication") != -1)
        {
             // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (cmdLine != null && cmdLine.IndexOf("someapplication") != -1)
```

Comment: Yeah, but ... let me put it this way. The cmdLine variable was never null before.